# java.swing JPanel not being removed

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a problem with my java.swing application!
So the problem is that when i use a method to create a JPanel with specific data and a remove JButton in the top right corner of that JPanel. When there is only one of that JPanel in the main JPanel and you press the remove button it gets removed and everything works! But when there are two of these JPanels only the second one gets removed and disappears, the first one gets removed from the JPanel but it doesn't disappear!
Any idea why this is happening?
If you have a solution please help.

This is the function that im talking about.

```
public void CardInfo(int y, String logoPath, CardDetails details, JPanel DebitCard) {
    JLabel nick = new JLabel(details.CardNick);
    JLabel number = new JLabel(details.CardNumber);
    JLabel holder = new JLabel(details.CardHolder);
    JLabel expDate = new JLabel(details.ExpDate);
    JButton removeCard = new JButton();
    DebitCard = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Image img = new ImageIcon(logoPath).getImage();
            g.drawImage(img, 295, 125, this);
        }
    };

    nick.setBounds(20,20,300,30);
    nick.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 20));
    nick.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    removeCard.setBounds(360, 10, 30, 30);
    removeCard.setIcon(new ImageIcon("commonJava/Resources/Images/do_not_disturb_on_FILL0_wght400_GRAD0_opsz24.png"));
    removeCard.setBackground(null);

    number.setBounds(20,45,180,25);
    number.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 16));
    number.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    holder.setBounds(20,85,200,25);
    holder.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 16));
    holder.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    expDate.setBounds(20,65,120,25);
    expDate.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 16));
    expDate.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    DebitCard.setBounds(220, y, 400, 200);
    DebitCard.setBackground(new Color(13, 17, 23));
    DebitCard.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    DebitCard.setFont(this.font);

    JPanel finalDebitCard = DebitCard;
    removeCard.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(DBUtils.RequestCloseCard(details.CardNumber)){
                cardsPanel.remove(finalDebitCard);
                cardsPanel.revalidate();
                cardsPanel.repaint();
            }
        }
    });

    DebitCard.add(number);
    DebitCard.add(removeCard);
    DebitCard.add(holder);
    DebitCard.add(nick);
    DebitCard.add(expDate); 
    DebitCard.setLayout(null);
    cardsPanel.add(DebitCard);
}
```

Comment: [Avoid null layouts in Swing](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing) Apart from that, if you find you need to tear down parts of your gui, you're probably doing it wrong. `CardLayout` is probably what you want

Comment: 1) Not related to your question but a painting method is for painting only. Don't do I/O in the paintComponent() method to read the image. This will cause poor performance. The image should be read in the constructor of your class. 2) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Be consistent!!!

Comment: *Plus* you're loading the images as files. [Better to load your files/images as resources:](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans) [or in Eclipse:](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)

Comment: `new Font("Ariel"…` probably won’t do what you think.  The font’s name is [Arial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial).

Comment: You are not using the parameter `DebitCard` but overwriting its value with a new object created in this method.